# Relationship between classes and header files

Tags: c++, class, oop, include, parent-child

I'm trying to learn how to use classes in C++. This is my file structure.

main.cpp (sueca.cpp)

```
#include "Card.h"
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Turn.h"
#include "Game.h"

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "\t\t\t.:: Sueca Game ::." << std::endl;

    Game sueca;
    //sueca.startGame();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Card.h:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <iostream>             // std::cout
#include <string>               // std::string

class Card {
    public:
        Card();
        Card(int&, int&);
        ~Card();
        int getSuit() const;
        int getRank() const;
        int getPoints() const;
        void printCard () const;
        void setSuit(int&); 
        void setRank(int&);
        void setCard(int&, int&);

    private:
        int suit;
        int rank;
};

#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card ()
{
    suit = -1;
    rank = -1;
}

Card::Card (int &isuit, int &irank)
{
    suit = isuit;
    rank = irank;
}

Card::~Card ()
{

}

int Card::getSuit () const
{
    return suit;
}

int Card::getRank () const
{
    return rank;
}

void Card::setSuit (int &isuit) 
{
    suit = isuit;
    return;
}

void Card::setRank (int &irank) 
{
    rank = irank;
    return;
}

void Card::setCard (int &isuit, int &irank)
{
    suit = isuit;
    rank = irank;
}


int Card::getPoints () const
{
    if (rank <= 4)
        return 0;
    else if (rank <= 7)
        return rank-3;
    else
        return rank+2;
}

void Card::printCard () const
{
    std::string naipe, nome;
    switch (suit) 
    {
        case 0: 
            naipe = "HEARTS";
            break;
        case 1:
            naipe = "DIAMONDS";
            break;
        case 2:
            naipe = "CLUBS";
            break;
        case 3:
            naipe = "SPADES";
            break;
    }
    switch (rank)
    {
        case 0: 
            nome = "TWO";
            break;
        case 1:
            nome = "THREE";
            break;
        case 2:
            nome = "FOUR";
            break;
        case 3:
            nome = "FIVE";
            break;
        case 4:
            nome = "SIX";
            break;
        case 5:
            nome = "QUEEN";
            break;
        case 6:
            nome = "JACK";
            break;
        case 7:
            nome = "KING";
            break;
        case 8:
            nome = "SEVEN";
            break;
        case 9:
            nome = "ACE";
            break;
    }

    std::cout << nome << " of " << naipe;
    return;
}
```

Deck.h:

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <iostream>             // std::cout
#include <algorithm>            // std::shuffle
#include <array>                // std::array
#include <string>               // std::string
#include <random>               // std::default_random_engine
#include <chrono>               // std::chrono::system_clock

#include "Card.h"

class Deck : public Card{
    public:
        Deck();
        ~Deck();
        void shuffleDeck(int&); 
        void printDeck();   

    private:
        std::array<Card,40> element;         
};

#endif
```

Deck.cpp:

```
#include "Deck.h"

Deck::Deck ()
{
    auto i = 0;
    for (auto s = 0; s < 4; ++s)
    {
        for (auto r = 0; r < 10; ++r)
        {
            element[i].setCard(s, r);
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

void Deck::shuffleDeck (int &times)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < times; ++i)
    {
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::shuffle(element.begin(), element.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
    }
    return;
}

void Deck::printDeck ()
{
    for (auto c = 0; c < element.size(); ++c)
    {
        std::cout << "card\t(" << c << ")\t";
        element[c].printCard();
    }
    return;
}
```

Player.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>             // std::cout
#include <string>               // std::string
#include <array>                // std::array

#include "Card.h"

class Player : public Card {
    public:
        Player();
        Player(int&, std::string&);
        ~Player();
        int getID() const;
        std::string getName() const;
        int getPoints() const;
        int printHand() const;
        void setID(int&);
        void setName(std::string&);
        void setPoints(int&);

    private:
        int id;
        std::string name;
        int points = 0;
        std::array<Card,10> hand;         
};

#endif
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player ()
{
    id = -1;
    points = 0;
}

Player::Player (int &iid, std::string &iname)
{
    id = iid;
    name = iname;
    points = 0;
}

Player::~Player ()
{
    
}

int Player::getID () const
{
    return id;
}

std::string getName () const
{
    return name;
}

int Player::getPoints () const
{
    return points;
}

int Player::printHand () const
{
    if (hand.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\t\t\tERROR: Player " << name << " has no cards (" << id << ")" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "(" << id << ") " << name << "'s cards:" << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        hand[i].printCard();

    return 0;
}

void Player::setID(int &iid)
{
    id = iid;
    return;
}

void Player::setName(std::string &iname)
{
    name = iname;
    return;
}

void Player::setPoints(int &ipoints)
{
    points = ipoints;
    return;
}
```

Turn.h:

```
#ifndef TURN_H
#define TURN_H

#include <iostream>             // std::cout
#include <array>                // std::array

#include "Player.h"
#include "Card.h"

// NOTE: I'd like to access the variable "trump" from the class Game, making it the parent of this class (one game has many turns)

class Turn {
    public:
        Turn();
        Turn(int&, std::array<Player,4>&);
        ~Turn();
        int getID() const;
        int playTurn();
        int getTurnWinner();
        
    private:
        int id;
        //int trump; --> use the trump variable from the parent Game instead
        std::array<Player,4> gamer;
        std::array<Card,4> move;    
};

#endif
```

Turn.cpp:

```
#include "Turn.h"

Turn::Turn ()
{
    id = -1;
}

Turn::Turn (int &roundNO, std::array<Player,4> &players)
{
    id = roundNO;
    gamer = players;
}

int Turn::getID () const
{
    return id;
}

int Turn::playTurn ()
{   
    for (auto p = 0; p < 4; ++p)
    {
        std::cout << "\t(" << p << ") " << gamer[p].getName() << "'s turn!" << std::endl;

        if (gamer[p].printHand() == -1)
            return -1;
        
        std::cout << "Pick the number of the card you want to play: ";

        int playcard;
        std::cin >> playcard;

        while (playcard > 10)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid selection!\nPick the number of the card you want to play: ";
            std::cin >> playcard;
        }
        
        //move[p] = gamer[p].hand[playcard];
    }    

    return 0;
}

int Turn::getTurnWinner ()
{
    Card max, maxtrunfo;
    int winner, winnertrunfo, points = 0;
    bool trunfo = false;

    if (move.size() < 4)
    {   
        std::cout << "\t\t\tERROR: Round " << id << " has" << move.size() << " cards." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if (gamer.size() < 4)
    {   
        std::cout << "\t\t\tERROR: Round " << id << " has" << gamer.size() << " cards." << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (move[i].getRank() > max.getRank())
        {
            max = move[i];
            winner = i;
        }
            
        if ((move[i].getSuit() == trump) && (move[i].getRank() > maxtrunfo.getRank()))                                                ///VER ISTO
        {
            maxtrunfo = move[i];
            trunfo = true;
            winnertrunfo = i;
        }

        points += move[i].getPoints();
    }

    if (trunfo)
    {
        std::cout << "\t(" << winnertrunfo << ") " << gamer[winnertrunfo].getName() << " wins!" << std::endl;
        //gamer[winnertrunfo].getPoints() = points;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\t(" << winner << ") " << gamer[winner].getName() << " wins!" << std::endl;
        //gamer[winner].getPoints() = points;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Game.h:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <iostream>             // std::cout
#include <algorithm>            // std::shuffle
#include <array>                // std::array
#include <string>               // std::string
#include <random>               // std::default_random_engine
#include <chrono>               // std::chrono::system_clock

#include "Turn.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Game {
    public:
        //Game();
        //~Game();
        int startGame();
        int setTrump();

    private: 
        int trunfo;
        int duration;
        Deck gamedeck;
        std::array<Turn,10> round;
        std::array<Player,4> gamer;
};

#endif
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

/*Game::Game ()
{
    trunfo = -1;
    duration = 0;
}

Game::~Game ()
{

}*/

int Game::setTrump ()
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> gamer(0,3);
    int player = gamer(generator);
    
    return player;
}

int Game::startGame ()
{
    int shuffle = 1;

    std::cout << "How many times do you want to shuffle the deck? ";
    std::cin >> shuffle;

    while (shuffle < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Please insert an integer bigger than 0.\nHow many times do you want to shuffle the deck? ";
        std::cin >> shuffle;
    }

    gamedeck.printDeck();
    gamedeck.shuffleDeck(shuffle);

    std::cout << "Deck shuffled " << shuffle << " times!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t * The player pairings will be (1 & 3) and (2 & 4). Let's proceed to name each player." << std::endl;

    std::string playername;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Type the name of Player " << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> playername;

        while (playername.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Please insert a readable name.\nType the name of Player " << i+1 << ": ";
            std::cin >> playername;
        }

        gamer[i].id = i;
        gamer[i].name = playername;
        
        for (auto c = 0; c < 10; c++)
            gamer[i].hand[c] = gamedeck.element[c+i*10];                                                                        /// APRENDER A PASSAR O ENDEREÇO DA CARTA
    }

    // Set trump card & suit
    int trump_player, trump_card;
    trump_player = setTrump();

    std::cout << "The trump card is (" << trump_player << ") "<< gamer[trump_player].name << "'s ";
    gamer[trump_player].hand[0].print_card();
    trunfo = gamer[trump_player].hand[0].suit;

    return 0;
}
```

Terminal Error:

```
g++ sueca.cpp -o sueca
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmCL0jl.o: in function `std::array<Turn, 10ul>::array()':
sueca.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5arrayI4TurnLm10EEC2Ev[_ZNSt5arrayI4TurnLm10EEC5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `Turn::Turn()'
/usr/bin/ld: sueca.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5arrayI4TurnLm10EEC2Ev[_ZNSt5arrayI4TurnLm10EEC5Ev]+0x7d): undefined reference to `Turn::~Turn()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmCL0jl.o: in function `std::array<Turn, 10ul>::~array()':
sueca.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5arrayI4TurnLm10EED2Ev[_ZNSt5arrayI4TurnLm10EED5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `Turn::~Turn()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmCL0jl.o: in function `std::array<Player, 4ul>::array()':
sueca.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5arrayI6PlayerLm4EEC2Ev[_ZNSt5arrayI6PlayerLm4EEC5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `Player::Player()'
/usr/bin/ld: sueca.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5arrayI6PlayerLm4EEC2Ev[_ZNSt5arrayI6PlayerLm4EEC5Ev]+0x76): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmCL0jl.o: in function `std::array<Player, 4ul>::~array()':
sueca.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5arrayI6PlayerLm4EED2Ev[_ZNSt5arrayI6PlayerLm4EED5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmCL0jl.o: in function `Game::Game()':
sueca.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameC2Ev[_ZN4GameC5Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to `Deck::Deck()'
/usr/bin/ld: sueca.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameC2Ev[_ZN4GameC5Ev]+0x75): undefined reference to `Deck::~Deck()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmCL0jl.o: in function `Game::~Game()':
sueca.cpp:(.text._ZN4GameD2Ev[_ZN4GameD5Ev]+0x40): undefined reference to `Deck::~Deck()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Additionally, I understand that these are very basic isses I've been reading "A tour of C++" but it doesn't go into much detail on how some things are done so I browse the web looking for solutions to issues occuring in my code. Trying to learn C++ by myself with some prior C knowledge. If you could recommend me some ways to progress, I'd appreciate it (maybe another book I should buy?). This program is my attempt at coding a popular card game from my country.

Comment: You have defined your classes but have not implemented them. Do you have files like `Game.cpp`, `Card.cpp`, `Turn.cpp`, etc.? If so you are not compiling them. Without implementation the linker can't complete its job.

Comment: You need to include the Game.cpp, Card.cpp, etc.. files to be compiled as well. This can be done by directly including them in the main.cpp , but this can bring other problems (as duplicate definitions , because the header files themselves include each other). What do you use to build your project? I only have experience with CMake

Comment: Sorry guys, I tried to resume the question to the header files as I didn't think the source files mattered as I'm only including the respective header file in each. Everything is updated now. I use g++ to compile, shouldn't I?

Comment: He meant you need to include the cpp files _to the compiler_

Comment: Right. So... Commenting Turn and Game classes it compiles fine, the problem is there.
I don't know how to code this. I simply want to use the getTrump() function from Game class in Turn class member functions. I have tried adding class Turn : public Game {}; but it gave me a error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Game’. I don't know which game.h or turn.h should compile first since I'm making them depend on each other, what's the workaround?

Comment: First of all, do not attempt to compile your `.h` files. Your compile command should look something like `g++ sueca.cpp Card.cpp Deck.cpp Player.cpp Turn.cpp Game.cpp -o sueca`. If you really want to use something from the `Game` class in your `Turn` class you should probably investigate _forward references_ and using pointers to class objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to step back in your book a bit, but I'll explain a little bit.

Include (.h) files typically exist so that you can have 10 .cpp files that make use of the declared class. This is where you put class Foo { ... } stuff. Then anyone who wants to use Foo can include the .h file.

The .cpp files are where you implement the class. I think you understand this.

When you compile, you compile each of the .cpp's and then link them together. Or you can just do this:

```
g++ --std=c++17 A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp -o MyProgram
```

This will program MyProgram (you can call it whatever you want) and include all the code from those three .cpp files.

It can be a lot more complicated than that, of course. But if you do a g++ line that is similar to the one I shows you, listing all of your .cpp files, then as long as you've implemented all the code that you've defined, it should build.

Comment: Thanks! Other users had already helped me getting to the solution but you explained it very clearly. However, I still have compiling issues related to the relationship between Turn class and Game class. I simply want to use the getTrump() function from Game class in Turn class member functions. I have tried adding class Turn : public Game {}; but it gave me a error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Game’. I don't know which game.h or turn.h should compile first since I'm making them depend on each other, what's the workaround?

Comment: You would need to actually provide a `getTrump` method, as I don't see one defined.  And I don't know why your `setTrump` method is dealing with players.

Answer (score 1):

In the old c++ days u had to define .cpp and .h. in modern c++ this is no longer a strict requirement. Even if u have static c++ has inline static which u can initialize the static in the header.

I suggest stick with 17 or above and keep everything in the respective header.

Where u want to use .cpp or .cc or .c is if u need to hide a implentation detail but doing so then u have to remember to include the .cc in your project for instance using namespace keep in the .cc or including a thirdparty library.

Also its good to know how to make libraries and linking,dll,so but this becomes more chores todo which can be just accomplished with headers. But not saying headers are silver bullet neither are static lib ,dll. They more like different flavours of what you can release with. Also u have ipc things like shared memory and network. But stick with kiss(keep it simple stupid) and optimize when u have to.

Also if u define methods with no implementation you will get undefined reference